# How to remove duplicate rows with exact match in two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have table `text_table` in PostgreSQL 12 database with only 2 columns: `text1` and `text2`.
There is an `idx_text1` index on the `text1` column.

For example:

```
       text1    text2
----------------------
   1   str1     one
   2   str2     two
   3   str3     three
   4   str2     two
   5   str1     seven
   6   str4     seven
   7   str3     three
```

How do I remove all duplicate rows (with exact match of values in both columns)?

In the example above, rows **4** and **7** (or **2** and **3**) need to be deleted from the table.
I would like to find the fastest way with an SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Without a primary key, such task is tedious. I think the simplest approach may be to backup/restore, like so:

```
create table tmptable as select distinct text1, text2 from mytable;
truncate table mytable;  -- back it up first!!
insert into mytable select * from tmptable;
drop table tmptable;
```

Comment: If there is a Primary key in table, how will script look in this case?

Comment: @Владимир: you said there was no primary key... so this is the approach I recommend. Even if you have one, this is likely to be the most efficient approach if you are going to delete a significant part of the table rows.If there are just a few duplicates, then you might want to check Erwin Brandstetter's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best performance depends on the size of the table, concurrent activity, the number and avg. size of rows, and **most importantly the number of rows to delete**.

For only few duplicates, no NULL values (or you don't consider those duplicates), and no `PRIMARY KEY`, this would do just fine:

```sql
DELETE FROM text_table t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM  text_table 
   WHERE (text1, text2) = (t.text1, t.text2)
   AND   ctid < t.ctid  -- exclude self
-- AND   pk < t.pk      -- alternative with PK
   );
```

Among duplicates, this keeps the row with the smallest `ctid` (the first one, physically). (Or the one with the smallest PK value with the alt. syntax.)

About `ctid`:

- [Postgresql group by for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659545/postgresql-group-by-for-multiple-lines/52670170#52670170)
- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66007/3684)

Your index on `(text1)` should help. An index on `(text1, text2)` would typically help some more, unless strings are very long. (OTOH, when deleting a substantial percentage of all rows, indexes may generate more cost than benefit.)

And consider adding a `UNIQUE` index or constraint after removal of duplicates to defend against re-introducing more of those.

Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)
- [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier)
- [Eliminate duplicate rows in a PostgreSQL SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373087/eliminate-duplicate-rows-in-a-postgresql-select-statement/8380283#8380283)

Comment: If there is a Primary key in table, how will script look in this case?

Comment: @Владимир: I added alt. syntax.